# Continuity of Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$, $W$ be normed vector spaces and $A: V \to W$ a linear operator. Show that the following statements are equivalent:
a) $A$ is continuous in $0$,
b) sup<sub>$||x||v \leq 1$</sub>  ||Ax||<sub>W</sub> < ∞,
c) $A$ is bounded.

For a) I know that I have to show a neighborhood of $A$ at $0$  shows that $Ax \subset W$ for some neighborhood $x$ of $0$ (in $V$).
b) I am not quite sure how to do this.
c) To prove this I can take any unit set(ball) in V and show that the mapping of points of this set is bounded in W by some $M>0$.
Can someone please help me write these proofs in precise Mathematical format? I don't have enough experience writing proofs.
Thanks

Comment: Is the exercise to show that the following are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### $$ a \implies b$$

$(a)$ means that

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\, \exists \delta > 0,\, \forall x\in V \text{ with } {\lVert x\rVert}_V < \delta, {\lVert Ax\rVert}_W < \epsilon.\tag{1}$$

Now, suppose $(b)$ did not hold but $(a)$ did.
We will show that this is a contradiction.

Since $(b)$ does not hold, we can find a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $V$ with ${\lVert x_n\rVert}_V = 1$ for all $n$ and ${\lVert Ax_n\rVert}_W > n$.

Pick any $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta > 0$ be the one from $(1)$.
Consider $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ given by $y_n = \frac \delta{2}x_n$.
Notice that ${\lVert y_n\rVert}_V = \delta/2 < \delta$ for all $n$, so by $(1)$ we should have ${\lVert Ay_n\rVert}_W < \epsilon$ for all $n$.

On the other hand, by linearity and the construction of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, we should have ${\lVert Ay_n\rVert}_W > \frac{\delta n}2$, and for $n$ large enough this is $>\epsilon$, a contradiction.
It follows that $(b)$ must hold whenever $(a)$ does.

---

### $$ b \implies c$$

We need to show that $A$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets.
Letting $s = \sup_{{\lVert x\rVert}_V \leqslant 1} {\lVert Ax\rVert}_W$ $($and note that $(b)$ implies $s< \infty)$, it follows that $A\left(\overline{B_V(0; 1)}\right)\subset \overline{B_W(0; s)}$.

Now, any bounded set  $U\subset V$ is contained in some closed ball $\overline{B_V(0; r)}$ of finite radius $r$.
It's easy to see from the linearity of $A$ that $A(U) \subset \overline{B_W(0; rs)}$.

---

### $$ c \implies a$$

Suppose $(c)$ holds but $(a)$ doesnt.
We will show that this is a contradiction.
The negation of $(a)$, that is, of $(1)$, is

$$\exists \epsilon>0,\, \forall \delta > 0,\, \exists x\in V \text{ with } {\lVert x\rVert}_V < \delta, {\lVert Ax\rVert}_W \geqslant \epsilon.\tag{2}$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be the value from $(2)$ and consider a sequence of deltas $\delta_n = \frac1n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$.
With $(2)$, this yields a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ in $V$ with ${\lVert x_n\rVert}_V < \frac1n$ and ${\lVert Ax_n\rVert}_W \geqslant \epsilon$.

Now, consider $y_n = nx_n$.
Then, for all $n\geqslant 1$, we have ${\lVert y_n\rVert}_V < 1$ and ${\lVert Ay_n\rVert}_W \geqslant n\epsilon$.
In other words, $U = \{y_n\in V:n\geqslant 1\}\subset V$ is bounded, but $A(U)$ isn't, which contradicts $(c)$.

It follows that $(a)$ must hold whenever $(c)$ does, and concludes the proof.